# create mercurial branch from another branch (non default)

Tags: mercurial, branch

How do i create a branch from another non-default branch (say Y) in mercurial

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can create a branch from any revision, example:

```
$ hg update -r 500 or $ hg clone --rev 500 // depends on what you want
$ hg branch newbranch
$ hg commit -m 'made a new branch from revision 500'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The CLI command for branch from anywhere is given by Rui's answer; I'll dig a little bit deeper and talk about branch options. Without providing any extra command line arguments, or completing a GUI form in TortoiseHg, Mercurial will extend the current branch with each commit. So, if you're updated to the tip of a branch (whether it's a head or not) your commit will create a new branch tip. If you're updated to the middle of a branch your commit will create a new head with the same branch name (ie: you'll fork the branch).

Answer (score 2):

hg flow "parent branch" start "child branch" -u "user"

hg commit -m"message" -u "user"

hg flow "parent branch" "child branch"

hg flow "parent branch" finish

i hope this is useful

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted but didn't know how to ask.